# Declaration of class_bbcode

Tags: php, declaration, bbcode

Hi Guys I run an old php board and I've a warning:

> <Declaration of class_bbcode::convert_emoticon($matches = Array) should be compatible with class_bbcode_core::convert_emoticon($code = '', $image = '')>.

really don't know how to fix, thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the prototypes! One has 2 parameters and yours has 1. And they dont look like the same datatypes either

Comment: If this is not new code, then I assume you have upgraded the version of PHP without first checking for compatability